# Why are both translations considered correct?

Tags: traducción

To translate "I was followed" into Spanish, Duolingo considers both of these correct:

```
Fui seguida.
Fui seguido.
```

Why are both correct? To my newby (or is it "newbie"?) eyes, the first doesn't seem to indicate the "I" portion of the sentence...???

Comment: In fact, the best Spanish translation would be *Me siguieron*. Which, incidentally, has no gender variations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The subject can be omitted in Spanish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-subject_language#Spanish_language), so both translations are perfectly correct. Most of the time, the subject will be guessed by the form under which the verb is conjugated. Moreover, in your example, the subject can be inferred without a doubt, since *fui* is specific for the 1st person, singular.

As for the reason why two translations are offered, it's to account the possible genders of the speaker.

Female speakers will say

> Fui seguida.

Male speakers will say

> Fui seguido.

Answer (score 2):

Duolingo presumably isn't designed to know your gender. Guys will say *fui seguido*, and gals *fui seguida*. Both are perfectly correct, just depends on who the speaker is.